# MongoDB - Move (merge) documents from one collection (secondary) to another (master)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have a requirement where I need to merge documents from a collection to another.

1. The number of documents to move is ~100k. The master collection can
   have ~ 1 million documents.
2. I can use both Java Mongodb support and Spring data mongodb.
3. I do not want to load more than say ~ 20 MB of data in memory.

Is batch processing (load, say 15 MB of documents in memory and update the master collection) the only way to go? Does it help to have a stored javascript (like a stored procedure) to achieve this? Can anyone provide a link to understand latter?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details on the "merge" process? Is it something like this
1. Load each of the incoming documents
2. Check if document already exists in the master collection
3. If it does not exist insert into master collection

You could author a simple javascript function to achieve this. Here is a link -http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/

Comment: So... load each document, if it is already present then update it else insert it.